# Optimistic way of checking null references in java

Tags: java

Can any Java proficient / expert suggest me what is the optimistic way of checking null reference or objects before using it to avoids `NullPointerException`?

In my code I've more than 100 fields and most of them are required in order to pass value in request, but I need to perform null checks every time before passing it in request to avoid `NullPointerException`

I have shown below a little piece of code where I'm checking for null values every time for each field (lets say of more 70 times in my one file) which looks not good, code become very ugly and unreadable. Is there any way by which we can write method and perform null object checks through it?

Basically I'm looking better, Optimistic and faster way for doing this, Any quick help is much needed.

```
if(amount != null && amount != "" && !amount.isEmpty())
        AIMRequest.put("x_Amount", amount);

if(currency != null && currency != "" && !currency.isEmpty())
        AIMRequest.put("x_Currency_Code", currency);

if(expDate != null && expDate != "" && !expDate.isEmpty())
        AIMRequest.put("x_Exp_Date", expDate);

...........so on
```

Comment: Make a method for this. DRY

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Do you mean DRY? :) nvm.

Comment: @keyser: I had to look that one up.

Comment: the real problem of the code is that it's error prune; if you copy and paste, and forget to modify one variable name, instant bug.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Wouldn't the *optimistic* way to check for nulls be to not check for them? ; )

Comment: What's the point of `s != ""` when you also have `!s.isEmpty()`?

Comment: `amount != "" && !amount.isEmpty()` is the same as `!amount.isEmpty()`

Comment: By the way, did you really mean *"optimistic"*, or did you actually mean *"optimized"*?

Comment: @tomse not exactly...

Comment: @assylias ... right - he should have used equals instead...

Answer (score 4):

```
add("x_Amount", amount);
add("x_Currency_Code", currency);
add("x_Exp_Date", expDate);

void add(String name, String value)
{
    if(value!=null && !value.isEmpty())
        AIMRequest.put(name, value); 
}
```

Comment: Hi bayou.io - Does this will increase performance etc?

Comment: @user4567570 - don't worry about it; JVM very likely will optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

According your `if`'s, conditions you are comparing `String`s, so make a method:

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    return s != null && s != "" && !s.isEmpty();
}
```

If you want to compare objects with this methods change the signature `public boolean isValid(Object o)`,

and your code will be clean as this:

```
if(isValid(amount))
        AIMRequest.put("x_Amount", amount);

if(isValid(currency)
        AIMRequest.put("x_Currency_Code", currency);

if(isValid(expDate)
        AIMRequest.put("x_Exp_Date", expDate);
```

But if you can collect all objects in an `array`:

```
public boolean isValid(Object[] os) {
    for (String s : os) {
        boolean isValid = s != null && s != "" && !s.isEmpty();
        if (!isValid) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jordi - Does that will increase performance?